# Why does Internet Explorer say "Error: Video playback was aborted" for HTML5 video?

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

I set up a very simple HTML5 video element on a page:

```
<video id="test" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" class="center-block" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="training-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But when I navigate to the page with Internet Explorer, the space for the video says "Error: Video playback was aborted."

[image: Error: Video playback was aborted]

And when I go to the network tab in F12, Internet Explorer hasn't even bothered to ask the server for the video. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that video playback for the Internet zone was [disabled in group policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2014/12/31/unable-to-play-html5-videos-in-ie.aspx) by the domain gods. Accessing the same page with a simple hostname got the video to load in the Intranet zone and bypass the block.