# IE - Loading HTML5 video across security zones

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video

I am working on a web-based tool that includes a number of videos. This tool will be stored on a network share, and will normally run from there. However, users will occasionally make local copies of this tool to take offline. So, I want to include some JS to check if it can load the video from the C: drive before loading it over the network, to cut down on bandwidth use. The local copy will be managed by an automated utility, so the paths should be consistent.

However, when I try to load a video from the local machine, I get a `Video playback was aborted` error. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925892/why-does-internet-explorer-say-error-video-playback-was-aborted-for-html5-vid), which lead me to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2014/12/31/unable-to-play-html5-videos-in-ie.aspx). I checked the suggest reg keys and they were already set to 0, except for restricted sites.

I believe it might have something to do with the video being in a different zone than the HTML page. When run from the local machine, the page is in the `My Computer` zone, and when run from a network share, it is in the `Local Intranet` zone.

Is there any way I can make this work? Or even a setting I can look at to verify that I'm correct in assuming that the issue is due to the video being loaded across security zones?

Comment: Files on My Computer are not served by a web server. Internet Explorer is not a File Browser. Your keyword(s) is 'Mark of the Web' often abbreviated to MTW.

Comment: Have you tried adding a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) to the webpage on the local C: drive?  `<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->` tells IE to open the local file in the Intranet zone.    P.S to @RobParsons: On MSDN, _Mark of the Web_ is abbreviated as _MotW_ or _MOTW_.  MTW is an [overloaded acronym](http://www.bing.com/search?q=mtw%20site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com).  Use what you like, unless searching for the docs.

Comment: The MOTW looks exactly like what I want, except I need it to work in the other direction... I need the network version to open in the My Computer zone. I've tried using `file:///c:/test.html` and just `c:\test.html`, but that doesn't seem to work, and I can't seem to find any documentation about setting the My Computer zone through a MOTW, so maybe it can't be done?

Comment: By default content using the file//: protocol maps to the Internet Zone... I think to get markup and script content to map to the My Computer zone you must embed it within a resource dll (with the MotW) eg. the html for the 'Export to excell' context menu extension in IE is launched with a uri of res://C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE/3000 (viz: use the res:// protocol)... ex... thx Lance.